# Non-interactive emacs regex substitute

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

Is there a (non-interactive) function in emacs lisp that replaces a matched regex in an arbitrary string?

i.e.

```
(sub regex search-string replace-string)
```

as in

```
(sub "[^.x/]" "beef./xxfoo" "")
;; => "./xx"
```

Comment: replace-regexp-in-string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see function `replace-regexp-in-string`.  Simple as that.

And to replace matching text in a buffer, you have `replace-regexp`.

The replacement does not need to be a literal string, but can involve retrieving parts of the regexp match and other manipulations. Use `C-h f` to see the doc for these functions.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where that function is in the emacs docs? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Sure, the Elisp manual, node [`Search and Replace`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search-and-Replace.html#Search-and-Replace). You can find it yourself using `i replace-regexp-in-string` in the manual.