# Use `replace-regexp` in program rather in interative mdoe

Tags: elisp

I tried

```
ELISP> (replace-regexp "war" "negotiation" "trade war")
nil
ELISP>
```

The results I expect is "trade negotiation"

How could use regex in elisp program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-interactive emacs regex substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235293/non-interactive-emacs-regex-substitute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mistakenly used replace-regex instead of replace-regexp-in-string:

```
ELISP> (replace-regexp-in-string "war" "negotiation" "trade war")
"trade negotiation"
```

replace-regexp's third argument is:

> Third arg DELIMITED (prefix arg if interactive), if non-nil, means replace
>   only matches surrounded by word boundaries.  A negative prefix arg means
>   replace backward.